# GNU Aspell - how to add a custom word list?

Tags: aspell

I am writing a large LaTeX document for the first time, and I recently learned how to check my spelling with aspell. My document contains a few names and bits of technical jargon that aspell does not like. For example, I would like to have aspell accept the word 'odometry' in my files.

I'd like to create a list of valid words that aspell can use along with whatever list it is already using to check a word's validity. I'd also like to store this master word list in or near the same directory that contains all of my *.tex files so that I can include it in my git repository.

Can someone provide examples of:

1. A correctly formatted file that tells aspell to consider 'odometry' a valid word,
2. The relevant aspell command + arguments required to use the above list

My attempt to figure this out led me to create a [personal dictionary](http://aspell.net/man-html/Format-of-the-Personal-and-Replacement-Dictionaries.html). Despite trying a few variations of filenames and command args, aspell never changed its behavior to respect this whitelist.

Comment: Does https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/325870/117549 help? See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/116283/117549 This might be old, but there's also https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/103644/117549

Comment: Thanks, the option to set the home directory for aspell is a step in the right direction. I may be able to figure it out from here.

Comment: Excellent; feel free to self-answer, if it comes to that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the option `--home-dir=.` with `aspell` allowed me to store the following lines in my repository as `jargon.txt`:

```
personal_ws-1.1 en 30 utf-8
odometry
```

Thank you to Jeff Schaller for providing the links that led me to this answer.